# How can objects be updated rather than completely written anew when sending through ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, objectoutputstream, backreference

The following achieves updating objects sent through ObjectOutputStream (in this case using sockets) but it has to completely rewrite the object every time to update the object on the other end because otherwise the object uses a back-reference which refers to the old object sent and doesn't look at the new one. I don't know if this will have performance issues if something like this is updated several times a second, but are there any ways to do this more efficiently?

```
ObjectOutputStream objectOS = new ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
while(true){

        objectOS.reset(); // Disgregard any objects already written to stream

        System.out.println(kingBob.currentAge);
        objectOS.writeObject(kingBob);

        System.out.println("Update HP");
        kingBob.updateCurrentAge(keyboard.nextInt());

}
```

Comment: No need to re-send an entire object several times a second just to check for state change. Especially for game networks with high through-put,you should really only be sending a light-weight signal to inform the other side the state needs to be updated.

Comment: @Vince Emigh, Rather than sending an entire object, send the field that needs to be updated?

Comment: Send an opcode (usually a single number) which informs the other side what needs to be done. Each side would listen for opcodes that conform to a protocol. If a client wanted to tell the server to update age, it would send the "update age" opcode (for example, `0`). The server would receive the opcode. Depending on the opcode, the server would set itself up to read more data (such as the age itself). Don't use object streams for this.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't really have the built-in concept of copying or updating an object generically or even detecting differences, the closest you can get is serializing an object to an array and back to copy it and that is noticeably slow and still requires some support.

The point is you are going to have to do it yourself but you CAN code that to work more generically.

There are only a handful of "things" in java.  There are the intrinsic types and classes that extend "Object".  If you pass two "Objects" to a method, that method can iterate over the two objects of the same type, reflectively pair the fields, identify the type of each field--if the fields are intrinsic then copy the value over, if the field is a subclass, recurse down that class to copy IT's members.  This will keep your original references intact.

It's kind of a pain but doable--maybe someone has written a library out there by now, I had to do it by hand..

If it fits your problem space then the better bet is probably to look at an RMI solution.  If your object is "Remote" then the caller can just call one of your setters directly.

Note: My problem wasn't exactly like yours but it was close, I had to detect changed objects between two databases, copy some changes over and log them.  I ended up annotating the fields I wanted copied.  When you have to use reflection--annotations are AMAZINGLY helpful.

Comment: Appreciate the answer! & I'll look at RMI